# Android handle multiple fragment animations from same gesture in the activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I'm new to Android and I have a very unusual design to to implemented.. It's really hard for me to search existing questions/solutions as I might not understand the problem precisely.. All I know is what I want to achieve..

I've spent a afternoon building up my MainActivity, which contains a FragmentViewPager and a fixed Fragment at the bottom of the screen + overlap the pager view. As you can see from the screenshots below, I can swipe left/right to navigate between weather and contacts view. meanwhile, the control panel is always located at the bottom.

The next thing is to add some animations. What I want to achieve is... if user scroll down the contact list (or do the same gesture in other swiped pages, e.g. weather screen in yellow), I will let the control panel slide down (with a small margin still showing on screen so later user can click to pull it back).

The problem is.. if I add dispatchTouchEvent (for some unknown reason, onTouchEvent didn't work for me, I have to use dispatch), I will override the existing gesture behaviour - meaning only the control panel will slide down, but I will no longer be able to scroll the contact list and neither can I swipe left and right to navigate different pages in the ViewPager.

I don't know how can I add additional scroll down/up detector without erasing the existing scroll behaviour in contact list and swipe gesture enabled in FragmentViewPager (the swipe between different sub-screens effect).

Below is the MainActivity implementation. Note that my scroll detection might not be accurate, it's for testing first... and I'm already stuck.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    private FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new DashboardAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MainGestureDetector(this.getApplicationContext(), findViewById(R.id.container)));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {

        return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }

    public static class DashboardAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public DashboardAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new WeatherFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new FavoritesListFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new ChildrenLocatorFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private class MainGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private Context myContext;
        private View myView;

        public MainGestureDetector(Context context, View view) {
            myContext = context;
            myView = view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onScroll: " + e1.toString()+e2.toString());
            Animation slideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myContext, R.anim.slide_down);
            LinearLayout controlPanel = (LinearLayout)myView.findViewById(R.id.control_panel);
            controlPanel.startAnimation(slideAnimation);
            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not want to customize the content view of the activity and override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` to monitor the events dispatched to the child view.

When you scroll the list view, the content view should dispatch all events to the list view so that the list can scroll as usual, in the meantime, you can drive the control up and down. Whether your views are constructed as fragment or not, does not matter.